# 'Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.' error when typing on a textfield (SwiftUI)

Tags: state, swiftui

I have two textfields, assigned to:

```
@State  private var emailAddress: String = ""
@State  private var password: String = ""
```

Now whenever I am typing on it, the app seems to get stuck and gives me this error:

> 'Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.'

I have a `StartView()`:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

@Published var loggedIn : Bool = false {
     didSet {
         didChange.send(())
     }
 }
}

struct StartView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

var body: some View {
    if settings.loggedIn {
        return AnyView(TabbarView())
    }else {
        return AnyView(ContentView())
    }
}
```

}

I have created a ObservableObject class of UserSettings that has `loggedIn` bool value. When the user taps on 'Log In' button in `LogInView()`, this bool value becomes `true` and a new view appears (`TabbarView()`)

This is LogInView():

```
struct LogInView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

@State  private var emailAddress: String = ""
@State  private var password: String = ""

var body: some View {
GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack (alignment: .center){
            HStack {
                Image("2")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text("Social App")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))

            }.padding(.top, 30)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)

            Text("Log In to Your Account")
                .font(.title)
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold, design: Font.Design.default))
                .padding(.bottom, 50)

            TextField("Email", text: self.$emailAddress)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 45, height: 50)
                .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                .accentColor(.red)
                .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))
                .cornerRadius(5)


            TextField("Password", text: self.$password)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 45, height: 50)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))
                .textContentType(.password)
                .cornerRadius(5)

             Button(action: {
                self.settings.loggedIn = true
             }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Log In")
                    }
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 40, height: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
                 .padding(.bottom, 40)

            Divider()

            Button(action: {
                    print("Take to forget password VC")
                    }) {
                    Text("Forgot your password?")
            }

            Spacer()

            }
            .padding(.bottom, 90)
        }
}
}
```

I know this error appears if I am updating the view while state is being modified (when typing in textfield). But I am not updating the view anywhere in the Log In screen. Then why this error occurs. Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me, you don't even need to import Combine! When you use `@Published`, SwiftUI will automatically synthesize the `objectWillChange` subject, and will call send whenever the property is mutated. You can still call `.send()` manually if you need to, but in most cases you won't.

```swift
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn : Bool = false
}
```

Excerpt from beta 5 release notes:

> You can manually conform to ObservableObject by defining an
>   objectWillChange publisher that emits before the object changes.
>   However, by default, ObservableObject automatically synthesizes
>   objectWillChange and emits before any @Published properties change.

This is the full code that is working fine for me (both iPhone Xr and real device, iPad 6th Gen):

```swift
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(UserSettings()))
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        StartView()
    }
}

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn : Bool = false
}

struct StartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

    var body: some View {
        if settings.loggedIn {
            return AnyView(Text("LOGGED IN"))
        } else {
            return AnyView(LogInView())
        }
    }
}

struct LogInView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings


    @State  private var emailAddress: String = ""
    @State  private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack (alignment: .center){
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    Text("Social App")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))

                }.padding(.top, 30)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)

                Text("Log In to Your Account")
                    .font(.title)
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold, design: Font.Design.default))
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)

                TextField("Email", text: self.$emailAddress)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 45, height: 50)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .accentColor(.red)
                    .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))
                    .cornerRadius(5)


                TextField("Password", text: self.$password)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 45, height: 50)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))
                    .textContentType(.password)
                    .cornerRadius(5)

                Button(action: {
                    self.settings.loggedIn = true
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Log In")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 40, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 40)

                Divider()

                Button(action: {
                    print("Take to forget password VC")
                }) {
                    Text("Forgot your password?")
                }

                Spacer()

            }
            .padding(.bottom, 90)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to fix it. Thanks! I am still getting error on Xcode, but the UI is responsive and not getting stuck.

Comment: Is your Xcode error showing in any particular line?

Comment: Nope. Takes me to AppDelegate only.

Comment: Try creating a new project and pasting my code and run. If that does not trigger the error, then you know you should concentrate in whatever difference there are. No matter how insignificant they might seem. Btw, I am running Xcode 11, beta 5, on a Mac with Mojave (not Catalina).

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is a bug. This message you got is also happening on this simple view which filters out list entries by user input. Just typing fast in the text field causes this issue. If you enter the first character into the text field, the UI stuck for some time.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var list: [String] = (0..<500).map { "Text \($0)" }
    @State private var searchText: String = ""

    var filteredList: [String] {
        guard !searchText.isEmpty else { return list }
        return list.filter({ $0.contains(self.searchText) })
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
            List(filteredList, id: \String.self) { t in Text(t) }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

A workaround is to move the @State variables into a model. So this seems to be an issue with @State:

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [String] = (0..<500).map { "Text \($0)" }
    @Published var searchText: String = ""

    var filteredList: [String] {
        guard !searchText.isEmpty else { return list }
        return list.filter({ $0.contains(self.searchText) })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $model.searchText)
            List(model.filteredList, id: \String.self) { t in Text(t) }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: works as expected for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be related to your issue, but in Xcode 11 Beta 4, Apple changed "didset" to "willset" and "didChange" to "willChange"
In Xcode 11 Beta 5, apple changed "willChange" to "objectWillChange".

Thus the StartView() should be:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {

var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

@Published var loggedIn : Bool = false {
     willSet {
         objectWillChange.send(())
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Corrected it! Thanks. Issue is still there tho!

Comment: Using both @Published and objectWillChange is redundant. You can remove the willSet all together and rewrite it as `@Published var loggedIn: Bool = false` and you can also remove the `objectWillChange`. Both get synthesized automatically.

Comment: Thanks! But any idea why I am getting the said error as mentioned in the question. ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't branch with if, use .opacity(_:)

```swift
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
//        if settings.loggedIn {
            TabbarView().opacity(settings.loggedIn ? 1 : 0)
//        } else {
            ContentView().opacity(settings.loggedIn ? 0 : 1)
//        }
    }
```

Comment: Please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why you should not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: Corrected it! Thanks 